# Anonymize IPv4 and IPv6 addresses with PHP preg_replace?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, ipv6, ipv4

I needed to anonymize IPv4 and IPv6 addresses so I coded this crude solution:

```
if (strlen($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) <= 15) {  // Sorry: 15 NOT 12
    echo htmlentities(substr_replace($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], 'XXX', -3), ENT_QUOTES);
} else {
    echo htmlentities(substr_replace($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], 'XXXX:XXXX', -9), ENT_QUOTES);
}
```

It works fine with full length IPv4 and IPv6 addresses like

207.142.131.005

2001:0db8:0000:08d3:0000:8a2e:0070:7344

but not with abbreviated addresses like

207.142.131.5

2001:0db8::8d3::8a2e:7:7344

I wonder if there is an elegant solution with preg_replace and some regular expression magic?

Comment: `preg_replace('/^.*$/', 'ANONYMOUS', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])` that will literally replace everything with *"ANONYMOUS"* ... might not be what you what but it fits the brief :P

Comment: By the way localhost is `::1` which is definitely less than 12 characters so probably strlen is not the best way to differentiate between v4 and v6

Comment: There is no need for [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php). The IP addresses contains only digits (`0`..`9`) and dots (`.`) (IPv4) or hexa-decimal digits (`0`..`9`, `a`..`f`) and colons (`:`) (IPv6). These characters are not special in HTML and [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) returns the unmodified input string.

Comment: Have you looked at _[RFC 4941, Privacy Extensions for Stateless Address Autoconfiguration in IPv6](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4941)_?

Comment: Indeed, you can't go by length. For instance, the global IPv6 address `2600::` is valid and is a router on the Internet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No conditional is necessary.  You can write two patterns and two replacements for a single `preg_replace()` call to process.

Target the optional numbers after the last literal dot in the string for replacement.  Then target the alphanumeric colon-delimited substrings at the end of the string.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/FPGaa))

```
$tests = [
    "207.142.131.005",
    "2001:0db8:0000:08d3:0000:8a2e:0070:7344",
    "2001:0db8:0000:08d3:0000:8a2e:0070:734a",
    "207.142.131.5",
    "2001:0db8::8d3::8a2e:7:7344",
    "::1",
    "127.0.0.1"
];

$tests = preg_replace(
             ['/\.\d*$/', '/[\da-f]*:[\da-f]*$/'],
             ['.XXX', 'XXXX:XXXX'],
             $tests
         );

var_export($tests);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '207.142.131.XXX',
  1 => '2001:0db8:0000:08d3:0000:8a2e:XXXX:XXXX',
  2 => '2001:0db8:0000:08d3:0000:8a2e:XXXX:XXXX',
  3 => '207.142.131.XXX',
  4 => '2001:0db8::8d3::8a2e:XXXX:XXXX',
  5 => ':XXXX:XXXX',
  6 => '127.0.0.XXX',
)
```

Pattern Explanations:

IPv4:

```
/         #Pattern delimiter
\.        #Match dot literally
\d*       #Match zero or more digits
$         #Match the end of the string
/         #Pattern delimiter
```

IPv6

```
/         #Pattern delimiter
[\da-f]*  #Match zero or more (digits or a b c d e f)
:         #Match colon
[\da-f]*  #Match zero or more (digits or a b c d e f)
$         #Match the end of the string
/         #Pattern delimiter
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using regular expressions, you can explode by `.` or `:` accordingly and replace the last two pieces:

```
<?php
function anonIp($ip)
{
    if (strpos($ip, ".") !== false) { // detect IP type by dots instead of length
        $pieces = explode(".", $ip);
        $nPieces = count($pieces);
        $pieces[$nPieces - 1] = $pieces[$nPieces - 2] = "XXX";
        return implode(".", $pieces);
    } else {
        $pieces = explode(":", $ip);
        $nPieces = count($pieces);
        $pieces[$nPieces - 1] = $pieces[$nPieces - 2] = "XXXX";
        return implode(":", $pieces);
    }
}
var_dump(anonIp("207.142.131.005")); // 207.142.XXX.XXX
var_dump(anonIp("2001:0db8:0000:08d3:0000:8a2e:0070:7344")); // 2001:0db8:0000:08d3:0000:8a2e:XXXX:XXXX
var_dump(anonIp("207.142.131.5")); // 207.142.XXX.XXX
var_dump(anonIp("2001:0db8::8d3::8a2e:7:7344")); // 2001:0db8::8d3::8a2e:XXXX:XXXX
var_dump(anonIp("::1")); // :XXXX:XXXX
var_dump(anonIp("127.0.0.1")); // 127.0.XXX.XXX
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/9toZ2)

Though I'm sure there's some obscure (or not so much) case where this will break, so be sure to give it a thorough test first.

Answer (score 1):

**Regex**: [`[0-9]+$` and `[0-9]*:[0-9]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/83OhtL/1) or `\d+$` and `\d*:\d+$`

Details:

- `$` Asserts position at the end of a line
- `[]` Match a single character present in the list
- `+` Matches between one and unlimited times
- `*` Matches between zero and unlimited times

**PHP code**:

```
function mask($ip)
{
  if (strpos($ip, ".") == true) {
    print_r(preg_replace('~[0-9]+$~', 'XXX', $ip) . "\n");
  } else {
    print_r(preg_replace('~[0-9]*:[0-9]+$~', 'XXXX:XXXX', $ip) . "\n");
  }
}
```

Output:

```
207.142.131.XXX
207.142.131.XXX
2001:0db8:0000:08d3:0000:8a2e:XXXX:XXXX
2001:0db8::8d3::8a2e:XXXX:XXXX
:XXXX:XXXX
```

[Code demo](https://ideone.com/0MW4DQ)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$string = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if (strlen($string) <= 12) {
    echo htmlentities(preg_replace('/(\d+\.\d+.\d+.)(\d+)/', "$1XXX",  $string), ENT_QUOTES);
} else {
    echo htmlentities(preg_replace('/((?:[0-9a-f]+:){6})(\w+:\w+)/', "$1XXXX:XXXX", $string), ENT_QUOTES);
}
```

Comment: Hey brother just a heads up, there are some syntax errors and `$string` is not defined in your snippet.